# How to set up your init method for a mobile application

Tags: java, javafx

For a better explanation it is here. I have recently started using Gluon to create mobile applications and I am running into some issues when I created the MainMenu.java file. I am unable to configure the init method and keep receiving errors like "String cannot be converted to a stage" and unsure how to fix this. It would be much appreciated for the help I am unsure how to proceed. I keep getting the error:

```
error: incompatible types: invalid constructor reference
 addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, LoginPage::new);
                                  ^
constructor LoginPage in class LoginPage cannot be applied to given types required: Stage
 found: no arguments
 reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I have tried to change the addViewFactory method and nothing as has worked, including placing primaryStage inside the last ().

This is the file I am receiving trouble with

```
public class AlexDemo extends MobileApplication {

    public static final String LOGIN_VIEW = HOME_VIEW;

    @Override
    public void init() {

            addViewFactory(LOGIN_VIEW, () -> new LoginPage(LOGIN_VIEW));    

    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(Scene scene) {
        Swatch.BLUE.assignTo(scene);

        ((Stage) scene.getWindow()).getIcons().add(new Image(AlexDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));
    }
}
```

This is the login page with code that works(omly showed some I have way too much with buttons, labels etc)

```
public class LoginPage extends View {

    private Parent root;

    public LoginPage(Stage primaryStage) {

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 800);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        //For the label displaying "Sign In" to prompt the user
        VBox login = new VBox();
        Label statement = new Label("Sign In");
        statement.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, 13));

        //HBox for the email the user wants to sign in with
        HBox firstUserPrompt = new HBox();
        Label email = new Label("Username/\nEmail: ");
        email.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 13));
        firstUserPrompt.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        TextField userPrompt = new TextField();
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {

        appBar.setTitleText("Book App");
        appBar.setSpacing(115);

    }

}
```

This is the MainMenu page on the click of the button

```
public class MainMenu extends View{

    private Parent prevPage;
    private Stage stage;

    public MainMenu(Parent LoginPage, Stage stage){

        this.prevPage = LoginPage;
        this.stage = stage;


        Label statement = new Label("Sign In");


    }
```

It does not allow me to run the application anymore after creating the MainMenu.java file and it is occurring within the first piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `addViewFactory` is

```
void addViewFactory(java.lang.String viewName, java.util.function.Supplier<View> supplier)
```

i.e. using a method reference for the second parameter you need to use a method (or constructor) taking 0 parameters. There is no constructor for `LoginPage` that fulfills this requirement; therefore the compiler does not accept `LoginPage::new`.

As for the errors in the constructors of your subclasses of `View`:

`View` does not provide a constructor taking no parameters. For this reason you need to invoke one of the constructors of `View` explicitly at the start of each of your constructors (as long as you do not use constructor chaining) using `super(<args>);` as the first statement in the constructor.

**Example**

```
public MainMenu(Parent LoginPage, Stage stage) {
    super(LoginPage); // use View(javafx.scene.Node content)

    this.prevPage = LoginPage;
    this.stage = stage;

    Label statement = new Label("Sign In");
}
```

```
private LoginPage(BorderPane root) {
    super(root);

    //For the label displaying "Sign In" to prompt the user
    VBox login = new VBox();
    Label statement = new Label("Sign In");
    statement.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, 13));

    //HBox for the email the user wants to sign in with
    HBox firstUserPrompt = new HBox();
    Label email = new Label("Username/\nEmail: ");
    email.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 13));
    firstUserPrompt.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    TextField userPrompt = new TextField();

    // TODO: add something to root???
}

public LoginPage() {
    this(new BorderPane());
}
```

Note that passing a `Stage` makes little sense, since it's the responisbility of `MobileApplication` deal with `Scene`/`Stage` creation.

Comment: sweet man thank you I appreciate the help and the time you took to help me understand this. Can you clarify the addViewFactory part? that is what I am a little lost on the other stuff I was able to figure out.